# c mkfifo: No such file or directory

Tags: c

Occuring a question: "mkfifo: No such file or directory" when i want to create pipe.
There are my code:

```
int main(void){
   int ret = -1;
   ret = mkfifo("/mnt/hgfs/data_transform/mkfifo_room/myfifo",0666);
   if(ret == -1){
       perror("mkfifo");
       return 1;
   }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much.

I hope someone can solve this problem

Comment: Welcome to SO. First check the obvious part: Does that path exist where you want to create your fifo? Do you have access rights to that folder?

Comment: thank your answer, I just checked the problem and it is indeed a directory permission problem

Answer (score 0):

```
ENOENT
A directory component in pathname does not exist or is a dangling symbolic link.
```

([Linux.die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo))

The path `/mnt/hgfs/data_transform/mkfifo_room/` doesn't exist.

Comment: thank your answer, I found that i haven't access to the folder